# Convert List<Enum> to List<String> in Java

Tags: java, java-8, enums, option-type

I'm trying to convert `List<enum>` to `List<String>` and set it somewhere. Also, enum list can be NULL sometimes. I have tried using Optional class.

It works if i try using Streams. However, i have to do null check before and after conversion.

**Sample Code:**

**Enum:**

```
enum A {
   VALUE1,VALUE2;
}
```

**Business Logic:**

```
List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(A.VALUE1);
list.add(A.VALUE2);

BaseClass obj = new BaseClass();
ChildClass obj1 = new ChildClass();
obj1.setList(list);
obj.setChildClass(obj1);
```

**Conversion Logic:**

```
List<String> newList = Optional.ofNullable(obj.getChildClass())
   .map(ChildClass::list). //TO-DO.. Logic to convert enum to string
   .orElse(null);
```

```
if(newList!=null){
new Object().setNewList(newList);
}
```

Comment: The last code example, `new Object().setNewList(newList)`,  makes no sense. The class `Object` has no `setNewList` method, but even if it had, there was no sense in modifying the property of an ephemeral object that is just garbage after the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
        List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(A.VALUE1);
        list.add(A.VALUE2);
        list.add(null);
```

```
List<String> collect = list.stream().map(Optional::ofNullable) //Stream<Optional<..>>
    .map(opt -> opt.orElse(null)) //Stream<A>
    .map(Objects::toString)  //Stream<String>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks!. Im able to achieve that using streams. Is there any way where we can try using Optional class

Comment: OP mentions the possibility of null.

Comment: @NaveenKumar if you really insist on using `Optional`, replace the map with `.map(Optional:ofNullable).map(Object::toString).map(opt -> opt.orElse(null))`.

Comment: @NaveenKumar although it would be easier just to use `.map(a -> a != null ? a.toString() : null)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner when using Optional I am getting `Cannot resolve method 'orElse' in 'String'` I believe you mean `.map(Optional::ofNullable).map(opt -> opt.orElse(null)).map(Objects::toString)` .